# Error while using Gazebo in groovy

Tags: gazebo, simulation, simulator-gazebo, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm new to ROS and my system is Ubantu 12.10 with Groovy Installed in it
Followed Steps from

```
     www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/StartingGazebo
```

Then when i tried to execute

```
              roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world.launch
```

I'm getting an Error as Follows

```
             Error [WindowManager.cc:96] Unable to create the rendering window
```

Anyone know how to solve problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55081/error-while-using-gazebo-in-groovy/) by [Srinivas](https://answers.ros.org/users/4161/srinivas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 47 on 2013-02-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suspect a problem with your x driver. Can you run glxgears without a problem? You might be better of to get an answer on http://answers.gazebosim.org/questions/.

---

Originally posted by [dejanpan](https://answers.ros.org/users/92/dejanpan/) with karma: 1420 on 2013-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1